# Positioning elements using AbsoluteLayout

Tags: nativescript

Have an AbsoluteLayout taking up the full page.

The ui is reporting the width as 480.

I created a label and positioned it at 240 offset

```
        titleLabel.text = "Label";
        titleLabel.width = 20;
        titleLabel.height = 20;

        layout.addChild( titleLabel );

        AbsoluteLayout.setLeft( titleLabel, "240" );
        AbsoluteLayout.setTop( titleLabel, "20" );`
```

Expected it half-way across right?

But it shows closer to the right edge.

Little bit confused...

Answer (score 0):

Considering label as a rectangle, the `setLeft` will take the left side of the rectangle to compare with the whole view. In your case, the parent view has the width of 480 and you `setLeft` for a child view, which is a label, of 240. The label will be rendered with the left side starts at position 240, and the rest of label will be drawn based on that.

For example your label has width of 50. Then you should set it `240 - 50/2 = 215`:

```
AbsoluteLayout.setLeft(titleLabel, "215")
```

Comment: Yes I expect setLeft() to set the left/starting edge of the view at the half-way point (not centered) - but as is, the view is much closer to the right edge. In fact doing a setLeft(300) - brings the right edge of the view next to the right side of the page - what I assume should really be 320. Could this be a DPI issue?

Comment: It WAS a dpi issue. I divided the x by platform.screen.mainScreen.scale and get the expected positioning. Thanks.